# What is the simplest way to handle images in Drupal?

Tags: drupal

I am used to TYPO3 where I just can upload an image within the content element an then just determine the size an so on.

Is there a way to handle images in drupal somehow like this?

Answer (score 8):

Image upload support for Drupal is a bit of a jungle.

The most basic way to do this is with image.module and img_assist. This will add a link below each textarea allowing an upload, and when you upload one it inserts a custom tag into the content body that specifies the image, its title, its size and alignment, etc.  Note that this inserts the image reference into the body text of the node and gives the author control over how & where the image appears. This may be all you need if the site is just for your personal use and you're looking to do something simple like insert images into your blog posts.

An alternative (especially if others are going to create content and you want it to always look good without a lot of hassle and user training) is to restrict the placement of images in your theme--let people upload images as attachments, and render the images in standard slots outside of the body text. This is often done using the CCK imagefield to allow specifying up to N images--so you add separate fields to the Create Content node where the relevant images are specified. One can be marked as special and you can pull that one out to be the thumbnail that goes with the teaser.  (IIRC, imagefield may not be ready for D6 yet.)

To make this scenario work better, you probably want images auto-resized to a standard size that fits into your theme, and a thumbnail version to be auto-generated. A module like imagecache can do this, though it's not the easiest thing to set up.

The IMCE module is a DHTML/JavaScript uploader UI that allows the user to browse previously uploaded images on the server. (There's control over what folders they can see.) IMCE has an associated CCK IMCE ImageField field type to replace the regular imagefield. IMCE also integrates with TinyMCE and FCKeditor to replace their own uploader UIs. (IMCE and IMCE's imagefield seem to work on D6.)

Some people swear by the Asset module for uploading & selection of previously uploaded content; I believe it can also help embed images hosted on Flickr and videos from YouTube. Currently only available for Drupal 5.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you're looking to do, but a good place to start would be by taking a look at the [filefield](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) and [imagecache](http://drupal.org/project/imagecache) modules for use with CCK content types. [Scald](http://drupal.org/project/scald) also looks promising, but is still awaiting an official release.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [detailed discussion of this topic](http://drupal.org/node/316884).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way , IMHO is using the image assist module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting to learn about drupal, but here are some of my finds in the Drupal-image-gallery department - perhaps one of these will do what you want:

[Flickrup](http://www.developmentseed.org/blog/2007/oct/24/unlimited-images-your-content-drupal-and-flickr)

[PROG Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/prog_gallery)

[Gallery2](http://drupal.org/project/gallery)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this screencast:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TLB9-1t_mrE

It cleared out a bunch of confusion I was facing when first tackling this issue. Following the setup outlined in your video will probably get very close to what you want.